# Escaping a few views from authentcation (Guest Users) in Django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've set a default authentication class as I needed most of `apis` to be authenticated before being accessible. However, I need `login api` to be available to all user.
I don't see negative authentication class in `django-rest-framework`.

How do I let my `login api` to be available to guest users while not making view level `authentication_classes` declarations?

This problem arose because I'm not using django's User model. How do I create `AnonymousUser` instance for my `custom User model` (not inherited from django's user model) and then permit that user to interact with the apis?

**EDIT**

Mark Galloway reminded me of mentioning the same issue with `permission_classes`.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to make view level `authentication_classes` declarations?

Comment: what's the config stanza you use to require authn now? i'm imagining that you could create a middleware to default to a less-privileged guest user for certain paths.

Comment: @RahulGupta there are so many views. Moreover, I want it to be easily configurable during development to skip authentication sometimes and if I do it on view class basis, it would be time wasting to comment/uncomment. for example, DRF's browsable apis won't be accessible.

Comment: @RobStarling I coded a custom authentication class as of now for those views. Also, I don't know how custom middleware would help here. Can you elaborate or provide a relevant link? Thanks

Comment: it was a half-baked idea that wasn't answer-grade. i'd have to play with it to come up with something presentable.

Comment: this looks vaguely interesting: https://code.google.com/p/django-guest/

Answer (score 0):

Authentication alone does not prevent a user from accessing resources. A combination of authentication and permissions is the actual determiner for this. For example, if your permissions are set to 'permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadyOnly' then users who fail to authenticate (eg/ no valid token) can still access the retrieve and list endpoints.

How exactly you want to define your permissions is up to you. For most of my implementations I use a global permissions setting but tag my log in endpoint with view-level AllowAny permissions. Additionally, view-level authentication for a specific is the only way to override global authentication settings.

For example:

```
class login(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
```

Comment: I know. Actually my question can be extended to permission classes as well. I want to exclude only 1 or 2 views from access protection out of a total of 10-20 views. Also, your `permissions.AllowAny` would work only when I'm using __django's User model__. How do I create `AnonymousUser` instance for my custom User model (not inherited from django's user model) and then permit that user to interact with that api?

Comment: To exclude those 1-2 views you will need to declare view-level permissions and/or authentication on those views.

I once made custom authentication for a user class which did not inherit from the Django user model. My authentication would set the user instance to one of my users, but if they failed authentication then Django will set them to AnonymousUser for you. However, I still needed to create a custom Permissions class which determined whether the instance of user was one of my users, or the AnonymousUser. 

Does this answer your question?